# Grant access only to certain ad domain group on IIS6, for web pages running asp.net and php

Tags: php, iis-6, asp.net, authentication, authorization

We are running IIS6 on Windows Server 2003 machine. We have a php based page (MediaWiki) and an asp.net MVC page. How can we configure IIS and Windows to allow access to this web pages only for selected AD domain groups, preferably without touching the applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url authorization for IIS6 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326020) did the trick.